# filter in typescript got error of '(string | null)[]' is not assignable

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of object, one of the property has a null value, I used filter to remove it, but typescript give me warning null is not assignable? since filter will never return null why typescript give me such an error?

```
const data = [
  {
    id: "123"
  },
  {
    id: "456"
  },
  {
    id: null
  }
];

const d2: string[] = data.map((d) => d.id).filter((o) => o);

console.log(d2);
```

demo https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-water-vio56?file=/src/index.ts:0-165

Comment: TS isn't smart enough to recognize this. You'll have to use a type assertion.

Comment: data is coming from api, why would I still need to declare type on d2 since null won't exist coz I've used filter?

Answer (score 6):

Typescript can't figure out that `.filter((o) => o)` will narrow the types of the array, not without some help. You can define a [custom type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) and use that though. For example:

```
function notNull<T>(val: T | null): val is T {
    return val !== null;
}

const d2 = data.map((d) => d.id).filter(notNull); // d2 is a string[]
```

Or an inline version that only works with strings:

```
const d2 = data.map(d => d.id).filter((o): o is string => !!o);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAUDGBvHXGASzgC4YAiARgCYBmSwgXwBpCCiTyqAWAVgBsTXGw6FcpCmACuAGzkssAXQDcWLADMZYYFGLgYYEFABy8uQB4AKgD4AFADcEcitZgAfIxYCUFZ3IkEDDunEQATgCmUDLhYDABMACEqOiyCurMGqCQsHC0aPBICAB0ALYIAA72cGi28CWkPiWaxHJQkeH2xma+6gD0-TA50PAF6IjI5VU1dQ1NLW0dXfYgfjAgQTDQ4cRgAOZzSUlrqkA)

Comment: oh man, this is so complicated, why TS is so weak to handle a simple situation?! haha

Comment: @NadielyJade type wise, all that `(o) => o` contains is that it takes a `string | null` and returns a `string | null` (and even that much needs to be inferred). Returning a `string | null` does not guarantee the types will be narrowed, since different code with those types would not narrow it. For linear code, typescript can step through the statements and calculate the consequences to types, but for code in callbacks, the type information doesn't say anything about when (or even if) the callbacks will be called. You and i know what filter does with its callback, but the types don't.

Comment: Fortunately, the types for `.filter` do let you pass in a type guard, and then it gets narrowed down as expected.

Comment: is there any other work around on this? I don't mind I change the way I code.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a type guard? It's basically the same code you already had, just with enough type info that typescript can do its job. If you don't like that i split it out to a named function, you can do it inline if you prefer. Anyway, you have two other options: 1) use a type assertion (ie, stick `as string[]` at the end of the line). Be aware that a type assertion is you telling typescript not to check your work, so if you make a mistake, it will not warn you. 2) don't use `.filter`, instead write your own for loop which does the filtering.